# Fin n nearest points to lines in two geodataframes

Tags: python, geometry, geospatial, geopandas, qgis

I have two geodataframes, one where the geometries are points and another where they are lines. I want to find for each line the n (in my case n=3) nearest lines to each point. Is there a way to do this in geopandas?

I know you can use `gpd.sjoin_nearest` but that gives you only one result.

I have also managed to do this in QGIS using `Join attributes by nearest` tool but I want to find a way of doing it programatically in a pipeline. I am open to doing it using any other tool/package I am just concerned about the algorithm efficiency... In QGIS it's quite fast but you have to do it manually via the UI.